# Display custom error messages, if data type mismatch while reading excel file into database(in C# Program)

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

I am new to .NET, Hope to get some suggestions on my below scenario:

Scenario: I have an external Excel file, which should be read and loaded into the database using C#.

So, For that I have created two tables:

1. Staging table (A temporary table which reads the data from excel file before loading into the Final Table).
2. Final Table (Contains the verified data).
   At the staging table, I need to  write a program to validate the datatypes and prompt the user by displaying the error message.(Eg: where  an excel  column contains only the numeric values and if any cell contains the text/string  in that particular column , C# Program  should result in displaying  the message( “ Text not allowed , please enter numeric value”).

In order to achieve the above, I want to write a stored procedure which stores the error messages in temporary table and C# program execute the stored procedure to read the error messages from temporary table.

I tried the above procedure by giving the non-numeric/text (“ABC”) value into the numeric column. But I did not receive an error message as it is taking as null rather than displaying error message

OLEDB Connection String :

```
 string STR_OLEDBCONNECTION = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + PATH + "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes';IMEX = 1";
```

Below is the SQL Stored Procedure to read the error messages into temporary table.

```
USE [EXCEL_DATABASE]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spexcel]       
AS
BEGIN
    --SET NOCOUNT ON  added to prevent extra result sets from
    --interfering with SELECT statements.
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @count int

   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempResult') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempResult

   CREATE TABLE #TempResult 
   (
          [Messages] nvarchar(max) NULL

   )

    --Incremental Table 1

   INSERT INTO #TempResult
   SELECT '[Incremental File 1] Column [Units] at Row: ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(255),(SCOPE_IDENTITY() + 1)) + ' is not in correct date format' FROM [dbo].[Staging_OEM] 
   WHERE [Units] IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(float, [Units]) IS NULL




   SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM #TempResult
   IF @count = 0
   BEGIN


          INSERT INTO [dbo].[Final_OEM] ([Source], [Geography], [Product Type], [Period], [Period Format],[Year], [Device Type], [Segment Type], [Platform], [Units],[Other Software Units],[Revenue],[Budget Units],[Budget Revenue],[Hardware Units],[Brand],[Price Band],[Segment],[Prod Rollup])
          SELECT [Source], [Geography], [Product Type], [Period], [Period Format],[Year], [Device Type], [Segment Type], [Platform],CONVERT(float, [Units]),[Other Software Units],CONVERT(float,[Revenue]),CONVERT(float,[Budget Units]),CONVERT(float,[Budget Revenue]),[Hardware Units],[Brand],[Price Band],[Segment],[Prod Rollup] FROM [dbo].[Staging_OEM]         
   END

   SELECT * FROM #TempResult
 END
```

C# Program to read Temporary table messages:

```
    static bool checkNumeric(SqlConnection SQLConnection,string fileLabel)
    {
        bool result = true;
        var errMsg = "";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {

            cmd.CommandText = "[EXCEL_DATABASE].[dbo].[spExcel]"; 
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = SQLConnection;
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                errMsg += reader[0].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            cmd.Dispose();
            reader.Close();
        }
        if (errMsg != "")
        {
            Common.writeToError("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "] Error encountered while reading " + fileLabel + Environment.NewLine + errMsg);
            result = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Common.writeToLog("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "] Reading " + fileLabel + " is successful.");
        }
        return result;


    }
}
}
```